# Активировать кнопку по успешной отправке на сервер Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть метод postRequest() для отправки Json на сервер.

```
Future<http.Response> postRequest() async {
  var data = await formatJsonData() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  var body = json.encode(data);
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://link.com'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return response;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to create processing.');
  }
}
```

На первой странице, по нажатию кнопки совершается отправка Json и переход на вторую страницу.
На второй странице нужно активировать кнопку при получении от сервера статуса 200.

```
ElevatedButton(                   
              onPressed: enabled
                  ? () {
                      resetVariables();
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const Scanner()),
                      );
                    }
                  : null,             
              child: const Text('Подтвердить'))
```

как можно обновлять state из метода postRequest()?
Или какие либо другие пути решения

Comment: Как вариант, можете использовать mobx(для отслеживания изменений состояния и последующей перерисовкой UI), а также использовать getIt(для создания синглтона и использования общего состояния)